# Windows shared filepath not working while Maven Build on Mac OS

Tags: macos, maven, filepath

We have created a maven repository to be treated as Remote Repository on our in-house build
machine.This repository contains all jars which we need for building the application.

Our developer machines are accessing this remote repository via path:-
 **file://ServerName/Path-to-Repository** that is defined in **POM.xml**.

It works fine when we are doing maven build on windows machines, but they fail on Mac machine. It doesn't work because there is a 'path not recognized' error.
So, what should we do?

we tried using following path on mac:
 **smb://ServerName/Path-to-Repository** 
but the same following exception came:

Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: No connector available to access repository mavenreponew (smb://Denimfreelancer/maven_repo) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:387) at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:456)

Comment: This is exactly why everybody use [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) and setup the server to provide http access, see infrastructure [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository).